# Example for Etale Morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm want to understand the concept of etale morphism of schemes using following definition:

A morphism $f: X \to Y$ is etale iff it is *** flat ***(1), ***locally of finite type***(2) and has the ***separable field condition***(3):

Here (1), (2) and (3) mean:

(1) For every $x \in X$ the induced morphism $f_x ^{\#}:\mathcal{O}_{Y, f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is flat

(2) There exist an open affine neighbourhood $U_x =Spec(R)$ of $x$ and an o. a. n. $V_{f(x)}= Spec(S)$ of $f(x)$ with $f(U_x) \subset V_{f(x)}$ such that the induced ring map $S \to R$ is of finite presentation

(3) Let $m_x \subset \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ the unique maximal ideal of local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and respectively $m_{f(x)} \subset \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}$: Then the induced finite field extension $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}/m_{f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x$ is separable

I'm trying to acquire the intuition for etaleness by considering following four examples

(a) $Spec(\mathbb{C}[T, T^{-1}]) \to Spec(\mathbb{C}[T])$

(b) $Spec(\mathbb{C}[T] /(T^d - 2))\to Spec(\mathbb{C}[T])$

(c)  $Spec(\mathbb{C}[T, Y]/(Y^d - T)) \to Spec(\mathbb{C}[T])$

(d)  $Spec(\mathbb{C}[T, T^{-1},Y]/(Y^d - T)) \to \mathbb{C}[T]$

My attempts:

(a) Is is flat since it just a localization of $\mathbb{C}[T] $ on $T$. Or a secound argument: Open embeddings are etale.

But what about (b), (c) and (d)?

All induced ring maps $\mathbb{C}[T] \to ...$ in (b),(c), (d)$ are quotient maps, therefore of finite presentaions. Since beeing from finite presentations behaves well under base changes / localisations, condition (2) holds.

What about conditions (1) and (3)? Why it suffice to consider in all cases only the localisation on $p= (T)$?

The main problem here for me is to analyze what hapens on stalks, therefore what happens with the localisations of the ring map $\mathbb{C}[T] \to ...$ with respect an arbitrary point /prime ideal $p =(T - \lambda)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. I guess that one can distinguish two relevant cases 1. $\lambda=0$ and 2. $\lambda \neq 0$ arbitrary.

Could anybody explain how to argue exactly for (1) and (3)?

Comment: @Ravi: Hi. I don't understand why the fact that only at $T=0$ the fiber has only one element imply that the localisation map can't be flat. Why it is flat if it has $d$ fibers? What criterion for flatness are you using?

Comment: It seems that my intuition was incorrect so I've removed my comment. You might want to look at the examples on page 7 here: 
https://www2.bc.edu/brian-lehmann/papers/flatness.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example b) is not even flat, so it is not etale.

Morally, what's happening at $T=0$ in example c) is that the fiber is changing from $d$ distinct points to one point: when $d>1$, this doesn't fit with the idea of etale maps as being like covering maps. (The technical term for this is that the map ramifies at $T=0$ - as etale is equivalent to flat + unramified, this provides one proof that the map in c) is not etale.)

Before performing the computations to show that condition 3) fails for example c), I should note that the condition as written in your post at the time of this answer is not correct. It should instead read as follows:

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes with $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X, y\in Y$, then $\mathfrak{m}_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathfrak{m}_x$ and the field extension $\kappa(y)\subset\kappa(x)$ is separable.

To check flatness, we observe that $\Bbb C[T,Y]/(Y^d-T)$ is a finitely-generated free $\Bbb C[T]$ module with basis $1,Y,Y^2,\cdots,Y^{d-1}$. By computing fiber products, we see that the fiber over $T=\lambda$ is just the spectrum of the ring $R=\Bbb C[T,Y]/(Y^d-T,T-\lambda)$. But $R\cong\Bbb C[Y]/(Y^d-\lambda)$, and when $\lambda\neq0$, $Y^d-\lambda$ splits as a product of linear terms, so $R\cong \Bbb C^d$ and it is immediate to check condition 3).  When $\lambda=0$, the condition on maximal ideals fails: $\mathfrak{m}_{y=0}\mathcal{O}_{X,x=0}=(Y^d)$ which is not even maximal.

For example d), the map is etale precisely because the locus of points where 1) or 3) failed was removed.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Two points are still unclear:

1. Concerning case c) that the map ramifies at $T=0$: What criterion for ramifying
are you using here that allows to see that this map ramilies at $T=0$ in obvious way? 

This one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_algebraic_geometry#unramified
or the "naive" one from the theory of Riemann surfaces?
 
Does it suffice here to say that since at $T=0$ the map has (set theoretically) another 
number of preimages $f^{-1}(T)$ than $d >0$ then it unramified in light of 
morphism of ***schemes***?

Comment: 2. By considering d) you showed that for $y=f(x)$ with $x := x_{\lambda}$ for $\lambda \neq
0$ the schematic fiber is $k(y) \times _Y X := f^{-1}(y) = Spec(R)$ for 
$R \cong \mathbb{C}^d$. 

How this concretely provides that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$
is flat and $k(y)=\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}/m_{f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x= k(x)$ 
is separable?

Comment: I know that generaly, if $Spec(R)$ is affine neighbourhood of $x$ and 
$Spec(S)$ is affine neighbourhood of $f(x) =y$ then the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$
is the spectrum of $S \otimes_R k(y)$, therefore a push out. Futhermore, you have
shown that $f^{-1}(y)= Spec(R)=Spec(\mathbb{C}^d)$. We know that the can morphism $k(y) \to R$ is flat und flatness is stable under base change.

Can the map $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ interpreted as the base change of this? 
Or did you had another argument in mind concerning the immediate verification of flatness and condition 3) for the case d)?

Comment: 1) The definition you linked is correct. The idea of set-theoretic preimages is good intuition, but there are situations where it doesn't capture the correct information without refinement (consider the map of schemes corresponding to $\Bbb Q[x]\hookrightarrow Q(i)[x]$ for instance). 2) The map of residue fields is the identity, which is obviously separable. The local rings are isomorphic (they're regular local rings in varieties of the same dimension) and the map is an isomorphism. 3) The computaton performed in the $T\neq0$ case from example c) applies directly to d) with no alterations.

Comment: Let us abbreviate $X :=Spec(\mathbb{C}[T, Y]/(Y^d - T))$ and $Y := Spec(\mathbb{C}[T])$:

Comment: ad 1): Ok, so if we work with the linked criterion then beeing unramified in $T=0$ 
(or using ideal notation $p :=(T)$) says that there exist a preimage $g:= \in f^{-1}(p)$
such that 
$k(p)={\mathcal {O}}_{Y,p}/{\mathfrak {m_p}} \to {\mathcal {O}}_{X,g}/{\mathfrak {m_g}}=k(g)$ is unramified, therefore not separable
(here I identify the points with prime ideals (therefore abuse notation $x_p = p$).

As you remarked $f^{-1}(p)$ contains only one element, the point corresponding
to the prime ideal $g:= (T, Y^d-T)/(Y^d-T) = (\bar{T})$, correct?

Comment: Obviosly $k(p)= {\mathcal {O}}_{Y,p}/{\mathfrak {m_p}} = \mathbb{C}[T]/(T) = \mathbb{C}$.
Now the problem: When I calculate $k(g)$ I get $k(g) = {\mathcal {O}}_{X,g}/{\mathfrak {m_g}}= \mathbb{C}[T, Y]/(Y^d - T))/ (\bar{T})
 = \mathbb{C}[T, Y]/(T,Y^d - T) = \mathbb{C}[Y]/(Y^d)$. But this is not a field.
The desired result would be that $k(g)$ is a quotient of the shape 
$\mathbb{C}[X]/(f(X))$ with irreducible, but not separable $f(X)$.

Comment: ad 2): Here I'm not sure if I understood your argument correctly. Let set 
$Z:= Spec(\mathbb{C}[T, T^{-1},Y]/(Y^d - T))$ and $Y$ as for 1), so we consider 
the prime ideal $p = (T - \lambda) $ and an ideal $g \in f^{-1}(p)$and the 
induced stalk map of local ring $\mathcal{O}_{Y, p} \to \mathcal{O}_{Z, g}$.
You argue that this is already an iso since both local rings are regular in varieties of 
same dimension. Firstly, why $\mathcal{O}_{Z, g}$ is regular?

Comment: Futhermore, how do you concretely use in your argumentation the result you have proved above
that the fiber of $p$ is isomrphically to $Spec(\mathbb{C}^d)$? I don't see how
this observation flows into the verification of (1) and (3).

Comment: I think you're turned around a bit here: $f$ is ramified (not unramified) at $T=0$. This means that the linked condition **fails**. In the language of the link, the condition on $\mathfrak{n}$ fails to occur, which is exactly what you find in your computation. Regularity can be checked by the Jacobian condition. Finding that the preimage is a disjoint union of points lets us check the condition on residue fields: the residue field at each point is $\Bbb C$ and the map is the identity. I added a sentence about flatness to the post - you may wish to reread.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, $ (T, Y^d-T)/(Y^d-T) = (\bar{T})=:g \in f^{-1}(p)$ fails to be 
a ***maximal ideal***. Thank you again for explanations... and patience :)